# Button style removed after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide/display a form submit button based on the selection of a tab. The default visibility is hidden. Once the right tab is selected, I am adding a style of visibility:visible to the button. Once the button is clicked, it goes back to hidden. Is there a way to prevent that? Want the button to display at all times when that tab is selected.

Comment: If you add your code we can check what's going wrong.

Comment: Is your solution based on bootstrap + js or what are you using? It will be easier to help you with that. Or as @Gerard wrote - add your code :)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form, you use the data in the form to make an HTTP request and then load the response as a new page.

If the button doesn't have the state you want in the new page, then it won't have that state.

Your options are:

1. Include enough data in the form so that the server side code can set the visibility of the button the way you want (and write the associated server-side code to do that).
2. [Prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of a form submission and replace it with Ajax.